# Taskbar (windowslist) settings

Tags: 23.10

I am using ubuntu 23.10 on my raspberry pi 5 and when i point the mouse on the task bar and right click nothing happens. I don't get the "Task bar (windows kust) settings.
I want to get to the "Add/Remove panel items.